# Windows default file browser implementation in blender

Tags: add-on, file-browser

I'm not proficient with programming or scripting but was wondering,
 is it possible to add/integrate the Windows File Explorer in blender? Almost all windows applications use the default file browser of windows.
Is there any restriction to use it in blender? At least is there any possibility to create a third party addon to add it as a feature? Or add those features into blender's file explorer.

The File Explorer has many user-friendly features that are non-existent in blender's default file explorer. I'm mentioning them so if anyone has any solution for them kindly let me know.

#Right-Click to open a folder in a new window/file location.
#Mouse scroll wheel to cycle between icon size(important when you are on a folder to view image thumbnail and quickly want to switch between list and thumbnail view).
#Drag and drop features like windows
#copy/paste option in right-click menu, keyboard shortcuts for copy-pasting.
#scrolling with the middle mouse button. It's there but no auto-scrolling with a middle mouse button click and drag.
#right click feature like 
#implementation of the forward-backward button of the mouse.

Kindly help me with any possible solution(I'm totally open to any ideas). Thanks.